# Can't access web sites when running iptables script!

Tags: linux, security, iptables, http, https

I have wrote script for protecting my machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh=1.1.1.1
http='1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2'

# Clear any previous rules.
iptables -F

# Default drop policy.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

iptables -N SSH_CHECK
iptables -N HTTP_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j SSH_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j HTTP_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j HTTP_CHECK

iptables -A SSH_CHECK -s $ssh -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allowing $ssh to ssh from his IP"
for web in $http; do
    iptables -A HTTP_CHECK -s $web -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allowing $web to visit my HTTP/S server"
done

#Allowing http[s] from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sport 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow ssh from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow working on localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

#Allow ping from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

The out put of `iptables -L -v` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 SSH_CHECK  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 HTTP_CHECK  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 HTTP_CHECK  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports http,https state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     localhost            localhost           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      localhost            localhost           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request

Chain HTTP_CHECK (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     1.1.1.1              anywhere             /* Allowing 1.1.1.1 to visit my HTTP/S server */
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     2.2.2.2              anywhere             /* Allowing 2.2.2.2 to visit my HTTP/S server */

Chain SSH_CHECK (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     1.1.1.1              anywhere             /* Allowing 1.1.1.1 to ssh from his IP */
```

1) I want to open websites with this policy but can't. why? how can I fix it?
2) What is these rules when I uncomment them on my script?

```
#iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Comment: In general, having a RELATED,ESTABLISHED rules in INPUT,OUTPUT(and FORWARD in needed) might simplify the rules to only concert themselves with NEW connections. (RELATED mainly seems to involve secondary connections, like FTP file transfers and ICMP packets related to the connection).

Comment: Using interface names on the rules means that you need to check the names...

The `iptables -vn -L` output is a lot more useful if you actually try browsing before getting the output...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing access to DNS, which is needed to resolve web access using names.

I would change the rules in these ways:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh=1.1.1.1
http='1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2'
if=eth0

# Clear any previous rules.
iptables -F

# Default drop policy.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow all related and established packets
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT

#iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

iptables -N SSH_CHECK
iptables -N HTTP_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j SSH_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j HTTP_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j HTTP_CHECK

iptables -A SSH_CHECK -s $ssh -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allowing $ssh to ssh from his IP"
for web in $http; do
    iptables -A HTTP_CHECK -s $web -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allowing $web to visit my HTTP/S server"
done

#Allowing http[s] from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
# Allow DNS - you might want to limit this to a few know, trusted servers
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#Allow ssh from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

#Allow working on localhost, using any IP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#Allow ping from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

The commented out rules:

- The first one will allow all incoming TCP connections.
- The second one seems to try to stop new TCP connections from being established using anything but SYN packets, which doesn't especially make sense... (I'm not completely sure about this, it assume the the `!` only applies to the itme directly after it, since that seems to be the common way to do things) [The answer to this has some details on that](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/tips-for-a-secure-iptables-config-to-defend-from-attacks-client-side) [More info at frozentux](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x6249.html)